# SVG Mask not working when rotated in Chrome (but works in Firefox and Safari)

Tags: google-chrome, svg, firefox

I'm building a painting tool with SVG that has various actions such as painting rectangles and rotating. One of the actions is to add a mask, effectively windowing the content to a specific area. To accomplish this, I'm using the svg mask element. However, when also adding a rotation, it seems that the mask is not working and the elements are rendering weirdly.
This is an example SVG:

`

```
<svg width="50%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-250 -300 500 600">
    <defs>
        <mask id="57656">
            <rect fill="black" x="-250" y="-300" width="500" height="600"></rect>
            <rect fill="white" x="-72" y="-141" width="235" height="287"></rect>
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <g transform="rotate(20)">
        <g mask="url(#57656)">
            <rect x="0" y="202" width="271" height="118" fill="rgb(128,237,51)" opacity="0.21"></rect>
            <rect x="3" y="167" width="313" height="318" fill="rgb(152,28,5)" opacity="0.58"></rect>
            <rect x="-65" y="-40" width="317" height="222" fill="rgb(74,103,68)" opacity="0.29"></rect>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

`

[how it should look (on firefox and safari)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBMNX.png)

[how it looks on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOPMU.png)

[how it looks on chrome without rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHTwz.png)

What could be causing this? is it a bug? I've also tried style="transform: rotateZ(20)" but that has the same issue.

Comment: luckily i've found that using clipPath seems to work, so I will be using that. However, there still seems to be an issue with <mask> and rotate with Google Chrome.

Comment: someone has reported this to the chrome team and it has been triaged:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1393659&q=component%3ABlink%3ESVG&can=2

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this issue is also related to **transparency** rendering.

Replacing `opacity` with `fill-opacity` applid to masked elements fixed this bug for me.

```css
svg {
  width: 20em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<svg width="50%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-250 -300 500 600">
    <defs>
        <mask id="m57656">
            <rect fill="black" x="-250" y="-300" width="500" height="600"></rect>
            <rect fill="white" x="-72" y="-141" width="235" height="287"></rect>
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <g transform="rotate(20)">
        <g mask="url(#m57656)">
            <rect x="0" y="202" width="271" height="118" fill="rgb(128,237,51)" fill-opacity="0.21"></rect>
            <rect x="3" y="167" width="313" height="318" fill="rgb(152,28,5)" fill-opacity="0.58"></rect>
            <rect x="-65" y="-40" width="317" height="222" fill="rgb(74,103,68)" fill-opacity="0.29"></rect>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```